# Persisting Data Using Hidden Forms in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, hidden-field

I have an input form (index.jsp):

```
<form action="process-mobile-number.jsp" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Enter a mobile number:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="telco" maxlength="4" style="width: 20%" required title="Please enter your 4-digit prefix."/>
         - 
        <input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="7" style="width: 70%" required title="Please enter your 7-digit number."/>  
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 50%"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the servlet that keeps count on how many times the system has been used:

```
@WebServlet("/process-mobile-number.jsp")
...
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

...

// initialize counters
int smartCtr = 0;
int globeCtr = 0;
int sunCtr = 0;

...

switch(telcoProvider) {
    case "SMART":
        smartCtr++;
        break;

    case "GLOBE":
        globeCtr++;
        break;

    case "SUN":
        sunCtr++;
        break;
}

...

// assemble counter bean
Counter counter = CounterAssembler.getInstance(smartCtr, globeCtr, sunCtr);

// create session
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

// bind objects to session
session.setAttribute("smartCtr", counter.getSmartCtr());
session.setAttribute("globeCtr", counter.getGlobeCtr());
session.setAttribute("sunCtr", counter.getSunCtr());

// redirect to results jsp
response.sendRedirect("mobile-number-result.jsp");
}
```

This is the output JSP:

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
<table>
    ...
    <tr><td style="font-weight: bold">Your number of successful attempts are:</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SMART: <%=session.getAttribute("smartCtr") %></td></tr>
    <tr><td>GLOBE: <%=session.getAttribute("globeCtr") %></td>  </tr>
    <tr><td>SUN: <%=session.getAttribute("sunCtr") %></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="smartctr" value="<%=session.getAttribute("smartCtr") %>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="globectr" value="<%=session.getAttribute("globeCtr") %>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="sunctr" value="<%=session.getAttribute("sunCtr") %>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go Back" style="width: 18%"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[image]

**QUESTION:**
However, when I press "Go Back" to return to index.jsp and begin another transaction, the counters are always reset to 0.
How do I make them persist with the hidden form fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each time your dopost method is called, you're initializing variable with value 0. Instead simply you can check if the session attribute exist, else set the attribute.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
  // get counter variables
  Integer smartCtr = session.getAttribute("smart") == null? 0: session.getAttribute("smart");
  Integer globeCtr = session.getAttribute("globe") == null? 0: session.getAttribute("globe");
  Integer sunCtr = session.getAttribute("sun") == null? 0: session.getAttribute("globe");
  //your logic
  ....
  //set incremented values back
  session.setAttribute("smart", smartCtr);
  .....
}
```

Comment: Hi, just a follow-up, when do I use getSession(true) vs. getSession()?

Comment: Well, there aren't any difference between them. getsession() is a short version of getSession(true). So it comes down to your preference.. :)

Comment: I read [here](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/httpsession.php) that getSession(true) will always return a new session, while getSession() will return the existing session if any, else, will return a new session if none.

Comment: According to HTTREQUEST java doc, it says it returns associated session or creates new if there is none: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)

Comment: it's always good idea to cross check ur reference with Java doc when u r in doubt... :)

Comment: You seem to be correct about getSession() and getSession(true) being the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count number times the of system usage, I suggest you should use static variable.

```
private static int smartCtr = 0;
private static int globeCtr = 0;
private static int sunCtr = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, this works, but I'm looking for an approach that doesn't use instance variables in the Servlet itself.

Comment: That means you do not want to store anything into server side, and also use different session to count number of time to use your system right?