# html selected = "selected" persistence

Tags: html, jsp

so, the user is on labs.jsp. they select one of the options from the dropdown menu and click submit. the form will post to itself, and reload the same page with whatever they initially selected persisting.  i thought selected = "selected" would accomplish this, but apparantly not. what am i doing wrong? code is below:

```
<form action="labs.jsp" method="get">

<select name="lab" selected = "selected" >
    <option value="0">Select Lab</option> 
    <option value="1">Physics</option>
    <option value="2">Chemistry</option>
    <option value="3">Biology</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="search"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected attribute goes on the option element, not the select element.

Sorry, accidentally submitted.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Trying to do this on the phone is a great, lol.

```
<select name="Myselector">
<option value="valuetopass">display text</option>
<option value="anothervalue" selected> option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that works for first rendering of the page.  I want the user to select an option, and then that option persists when the page reloads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051100/persisting-data-using-hidden-forms-in-jsp  Check this out.